# Viewbox changing width of element

Tags: svg

Would somebody be able to explain to me why adding `viewBox="0 0 612 100"` in the snippet below changes the width of the embedded rectangle?  Based on everything I know about viewbox if the numbers match the user units of the SVG, no zooming or panning should be done, and thus the size of the two rectangles should be the same.

```html
<div>
  <svg width='612pt' height='100pt' xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <rect width="100pt" height="100pt" />
  </svg>
</div>
<div>
  <svg width='612pt' height='100pt' viewBox="0 0 612 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <rect width="100pt" height="100pt"/>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your viewbox is measured in *pixels* (`px` - also the default unit in SVG), while you have measured the other widths/heights in *points* (`pt`).

[Point vs Pixel: What is the difference?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/199/point-vs-pixel-what-is-the-difference)

Use pixels all over, and things will work the way you expect:

```html
<svg width="200" height="150" viewBox="0 0 200 150" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="pink"/>
    <rect width="100pt" height="100pt" fill="red"/>
    <rect width="100" height="100" fill="green"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: See [SVG Units](https://oreillymedia.github.io/Using_SVG/guide/units.html) for all unit documentation. A **pt** == 0.75 **px**

Comment: Some hot Occam's Razor action here.  I could have sworn I read the units of `viewBox` was inherited from that of the `svg` element, but looks like I'm wrong.   Thank you to both of you.